# android: Sending Emails without User Intervention...Time interval? Service unavailable?

Tags: android, email, android-asynctask

I am working on sending an activation code to the user's email account using the below code (following from the site `Sending Emails without User Intervention (no Intents) in Android` http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android).

### Method:

The idea is simple: Just to send email together with the activation code in Background using the user's email to send back to user's email.

### Question:

Everything is working perfectly for the first time pressing the activation button, and the activation code is well received in the designated email.

However, when I press the activation button starting from the second time, it will just toast out the message "Generating activation code" but without the "Activation code sent successfully!\nPlease check email after 5 minutes" and thereby no email is received at all.

I would like to ask

1. Is there any minimum time interval for such service (`smtp.gmail.com`) to be performed? I have pressed again after 5 minutes and the email still cannot be sent. If not, how could the codes be modified?
2. Is it possible for emails other than gmail?
3. If my app is published using this service, in that case, many users may request activation code at the same time, would the service be unavailable?

Thanks in advance!!

### Coding as follows:

```
button_activation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        custom_email = EditText_email.getText().toString();
        custom_email_pw = EditText_email_pw.getText().toString();
        if (custom_email.length()!=0 && custom_email_pw.length()!=0)
        {
            SharedPreferences settings = Settings.this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();
            e.putString("custom_email",custom_email);
            e.putString("custom_email_pw",custom_email_pw);
            e.commit();

            SendTask sTask = new SendTask();    
            sTask.execute();
            return;
        }


class SendTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String>
{    
    @Override    
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {    
        Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Generating Activation code...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        super.onPreExecute();    
    }    

    @Override    
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) 
    {           
        {
            SharedPreferences settings = Settings.this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);
            custom_email = settings.getString("custom_email",null);
            custom_email_pw = settings.getString("custom_email_pw",null);


            Looper.prepare();  
            Mail m = new Mail(custom_email, custom_email_pw);
            String[] toArr = {custom_email};
            m.set_to(toArr);
            m.set_from("from@gmail.com");
            m.set_subject("App: Email Activation Code");
            m.set_body("The email Activation Code is 123");

            try 
            { 
                if(m.send()) 
                {                       
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Activation code sent successfully!\nPlease check email after 5 minutes.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  // success
                } 
                else 
                {                       
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Activation code sending failure!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  // failure
                } 
            } 
            catch(Exception e) 
            {           
                Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "There were problems sending activation code!" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // some other problem
            }               
            Looper.loop();
        }
        return "";    
    }    

    @Override    
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
    {    
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);    
    }    

    @Override    
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) 
    {    
        super.onPostExecute(r);    
    }    
}
```